# Finding max value from list without using max function. Must return none if list empty?

Tags: python

Basically I am trying to use to find the max of the list of values without calling the max function. The code I have works but the problem is there is a stipulation that if list is empty, the function should return `none`. Currently I get an error `out of range` since I'm using an index to get my largest value from the sorted list.

```
SURVEY_RESULTS = [25,30,100,88,56]

def maximum(x):
    response_list = []
    for response in x:
        LifeExp = response
        response_list.append(LifeExp)
    response_list.sort()
    max_val = response_list[-1]
    return max_val
        
maximum(SURVEY_RESULTS)
```

Comment: im pretty sure your teacher wont like this answer any better than using max ... sort feels like its against the intent of this lesson

Comment: Thank you for the heads up hopefully it is better now without index or built in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an if-statement.

```
SURVEY_RESULTS = [25,30,100,88,56]

def maximum(x):
    if len(x) != 0:
        response_list = [] 
        for response in x: 
            LifeExp = response 
            response_list.append(LifeExp) 
        response_list.sort() 
        max_val = response_list[-1] 
        return max_val
    else:
        return "none"

maximum(SURVEY_RESULTS)
```

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. I also replaced the len (I should've specified I can't use built in functions at all) with a count() I made. And it's looking good! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
SURVEY_RESULTS = [25,30,100,88,56]

def maximum(x):
    return  sorted(x)[0] if len(x) > 0 else None

maxium(SURVEY_RESULTS)
```